# Value of Graphics g in paint(Graphics g) method Container class

Tags: java, swing, awt

The official documentation paint(Graphics g) method says:

> Paints the container. This forwards the paint to any lightweight components that 
>   are children of this container. If this method is reimplemented, super.paint(g) 
>   should be called so that lightweight components are properly rendered. If a child 
>   component is entirely clipped by the current clipping setting in g, paint() will 
>   not be forwarded to that child.
>   g - the specified Graphics window

But nowhere I found what is the function of `Graphic` object passed as parameter.

Can anybody explain its significance.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)? If not, then that is where I'd start.

Comment: Graphics represents the surface into which you paint to, this is then renderers to the screen...

Answer (score 3):

"Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`," as mentioned in [*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks). The instance of `Graphics` supplied to `paintComponent()`, sometimes called the *graphics context*, allows a Java program to manipulate GUI structures owned by the host OS. The classes `Graphics` and `Graphics2D` are abstract; concrete implementations are OS-dependent and purposely *not* exposed in the API.